# How do I play a video from Cloudkit on tvOS?

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, cloudkit, tvos, apple-tv

I have a problem i have been trying to solve for a day and i tired of beating my head aaginst the wall. Anyone know how to do this?

Number 1 Works Great

1. Works Great

   ```
   - (void) viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"];
       AVPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
       self.player = avPlayer;
       [self.player play];
   }
   ```
2. Does not work

   ```
   - (void) viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       CKAsset *asset = record[@"VideoFile"];
       AVPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:asset.fileURL];
       self.player = avPlayer;
       [self.player play];
   }
   ```
3. Does not work

   ```
   - (void) viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       CKAsset *asset = record[@"VideoFile"];
       NSString *fileName = record[@"videoFileKey"];
       NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:asset.fileURL];
       NSString *cachesDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
       NSString *path = [cachesDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4", fileName]];
       [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

       if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
            AVPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
            self.player = avPlayer;
            [self.player play];
       }
    }
   ```

Comment: In option 3, where do you set the url? And what if you use the AVPlayer code like you did for option 1?

Comment: The url is from the asset.fileURL and the fileName is gotten from a record in cloud kit. If you check the container for the app the file is being saved correctly and can be extracted and played in quicktime, it just won't play in AVPlayer from the caches directory